# Import/Export of Mongo Collections, Preserving _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a MEAN database application with a number of Mongo collections with hierarchical relationships via ObjectId.  A copy of the application works locally offline, and another copy runs on the production server.

The data contain collectively describe rules and content that drive a complex process.  These data need to be entered offline so that these processes can be tested before the data go into the production environment.

What I assumed I would be able to easily do is to export selected documents as JSON, then relatively simply import them into the production database.  So, the system would have a big "Export" button that would take the current document and all subdocuments and related documents, and export them as a single JSON file.  Then, my "Import" button would parse that JSON file on the production server.

So, exporting is no problem.  Did that in a couple of hours.

But, I quickly found that when I import a document, its _id field value is not preserved.  This breaks relationships, obviously.

I have considered writing parsing routines that preserved these relationships by programmatically setting ObjectIds in parent documents after the child documents have been saved.  This will be a huge headache though.

I'm hoping there is either:
a) ... and easy way to import a JSON document with _id fields intact, or ...
b) ... another way to accomplish this entirely that is easier than I am making it.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: There is a lot of writing here that actually tells people nothing about what you have done. What did you use to "export" the data and/or "import" the data if you have even tried? You should be using `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` which are typically bundled or in a "tools` package if you just installed the server only. These preserve and import correctly the `_id`. If of course you are using them correctly. Show what you have done.

Comment: Perhaps there wasn't enough information.  The method I have used is based on JSON.stringify()  (for export) and JSON.parse() (for import).  JSON.stringify() will happily export, and JSON.parse() will happily digest.  But, then I programmatically walk the resultant collections, creating new documents with the create() method of Mongoose models.  This works just fine, except that either Mongoose or Mongo overwrites the _id value with a newly-generated value.

Comment: The point is your question does not show what you are doing, and clearly you are doing something wrong. You need to show the code, then we can point out the faullts. Mongoose isn't "doing things to you", your code is what is wrong here. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35467787/edit) link on your question to remove the backstory and musing and just show us what you are doing.

Comment: That sounds really mean! Why can't it import the exported collection in MongoCompas, i just don't understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always got to be someone that doesn't know the answer who complains about the question.  The question is clear and the problem is familiar.

Indeed, Mongoose will overwrite any value you provide for _id when you create a document either via the create() method or using the constructor (var thing = new Thing()).

Also, mongoexport/mongoimport will not fill the need to do this programmatically, at least not easily.

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to export a subset of documents, along with any related documents, keeping references intact.  Then, you want to import this data into a remote system, again, keeping references intact.

The approach you took would work just fine except it will destroy all references, as you found out.

I've worked on a similar problem and I believe that the best way to do this is to do what it sounds like you wanted to avoid.  That is, you'll iterate over your collections and let Mongo generate its _ids as it will.  Add your child documents first, then set the references correctly in your parent documents.  I really don't think there is a better way that still gives you granular control.

Comment: You're right, that's what I wanted to avoid, but I've done a lot of reading about this and think it's probably the best way.  It also lets me do validation.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

In current version of mongodb you can use db.copyDatabase(). Start current instance of mongodb where you want to copy database and run following command:

`db.copyDatabase(fromDB, toDB)`.

For more options and details refer to [db.copyDatabase()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/)